# Python 3.7 ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, msys, msys2

I'm using MSYS2 but without pip (SSL error), and when I try to run

```
python vin.py
```

It throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vin.py", line 1, in <module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

What can I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `requests` module is not part of the Python standard library. Have you installed it on your system?

Comment: I have installed `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-requests` and it still throws an error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you installed the `requests` module for Python 3 while you are running Python 2.

To specifically install the package for Python 2, try entering this command:

```
pip2 install requests
```

or

```
python -m pip install requests
```

If you want to run the script with Python 3 instead, simply change `python` to `python3`, so:

```
python3 vin.py
```

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: Or maybe run Python 3, to get the Python 3 module that's been installed?

Comment: @Blckknght You may be right. I've updated my answer according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/):

First create a virtualenv for your project and activate it:

```sh
python -m venv my_project
source my_project/bin/activate
```

Then install [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```sh
pip install requests
```

To test: run python and import requests

```py
>>> import requests
```